# Dealing with missing data for date variable where missingness is meaningful

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-transformation, missing-data

I have the data where there are a lot of variables which contain dates when the event occured and NA when it did not have place. Now I wonder how to handle this issue properly. I'm working with this in R (but it does not probably matter). The approaches I have been thinking about

1. Convert NA to 0 value. Then set a variable as ordered factor variable (cause number of years in my dataset is limited), but there is this issue with 0 (NA). When it is obvious that e.g. 2016 < 2017 < 2018, so years are clearly ordered, it is not true for NA coded as 0 that 0 < 2016. Should I then keep it as unordered or maybe continous?
2. The second approach I was thinking about was to do all from the step 1, so to convert NAs to 0, then set variable as ordered factor and besides that to create a second variable - Event Occured 0 (no) / 1(yes) and later study the influence of interaction between as.factor(year_variable) * event_occured on 
   a dependent variable.

What would be a proper choice?

Best wishes

Comment: Sounds like you've got right censored data. Would help to have more info about what your objective is, but check out survival analysis. Cox proportional hazards is the basic failure time model. You can modify it in various problem-dependent ways.

Comment: To be more precise these date variables are independent variables (there are also other variables in dataset which are not dates). Dependent variable is a rate of return. So the goal is to see what are the predictors for this dependent variable.

Comment: Do you know when the dates stopped being recorded? I.e. Do you know the latest date by which the event had not occurred in the missing data case?

Comment: Yes, I have a date when a specific observation was saved to dataset.

Comment: That's good. In that case I'd recommend imputing the missing dates with a Cox PH model using the remaining independent variables as predictors.